# I have to train the combined models and combining them in train loop instead of making single data loader

Tags: concatenation, feature-extraction, loss, dataloader

I am applying feature concatenation by concatenating features of both models before fc and then putting classifier on them. Instead of making combine data loader, I used single data loaders and combined them in train loop using zip function.

Am I doing right in for loop this part and in train_loss and in train_accuracy?

```
def train_fn(concat_model,train_loader_A, train_loader_B):
concat_model.train()
print("training start")
counter=0
training_run_loss=0.0
train_running_correct=0.0
for i, ((input1,target1), (input2,target2)) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(cycle(train_loader_A), train_loader_B)),total=int(len(dataset_train_A+dataset_train_B)/train_loader_A.batch_size+train_loader_B.batch_size)): 
    counter+=1
    # extract dataset
    input1 = input1.to(device)
    input2 = input2.to(device)
    target1 = target1.to(device)
    target2 = target2.to(device)
    # zero_out the gradient
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output=concat_model(input1, input2)
    loss=criterion(output,target1)
    training_run_loss+=loss.item()
    _,preds=torch.max(output.data,1)
    train_running_correct+=(preds==target1).sum().item()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    ###################### state computation ###################
train_loss=training_run_loss/len(train_loader_A.dataset+train_loader_B.dataset)
train_loss_ep.append(train_loss)
train_accuracy=100.* train_running_correct/len(train_loader_A.dataset+train_loader_B.dataset)
train_accuracy_ep.append(train_accuracy)
print(f"train Loss:{train_loss:.4f}, train Acc:{train_accuracy:0.2f}")
return train_loss_ep,train_accuracy_epere
```